# PHP - Problem with permissions using SESSION

Tags: php

First of all, I'm completely new at this so be patient.

So there are different roles in my database like `admin` and `saf`and if the person logged in is an admin I want them to see everything but if the person logged in is saf I just want them to see the `Dashboard`and`SAF`.

If you need any other code I can provide it but I think this is enough??

[image: database]

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

$ligaBD=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pap"); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) { 
    header('Location: login.html'); 
    exit(); 
} 

if (!isset($_SESSION['role']) || ($_SESSION['role'] != 'admin')) { 

?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="admin.php">Dashboard</a></li>

    <li><a href="biblioteca.php">Biblioteca</a></li>
    <li><a href="conselhoadmin.php">Conselho Administrativo</a></li>
    <li><a href="saf.php">SAF</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Bem-vindo, admin <?=$_SESSION['name']?></a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="https:a"><img src="./images/mail.png" alt="la" height="13" width="20" /></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>

<?php

}else if (!isset($_SESSION['role']) || ($_SESSION['role'] != 'saf')) {
?>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="admin.php">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="saf.php">SAF</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Bem-vindo, saf @login</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="https:a/"><img src="./images/mail.png" alt="la" height="13" width="20" /></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./login.html">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>

<?php
    mysqli_close($ligaBD);
?>
```

What happens to me with this code is that when I log-in as a SAF user I can see the admin features anyway.

I'd be really appreciated if you could help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are messing up with `if` conditions.

First `if` condition should be:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['role']) && ($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin')) {
 // Show admin role links.
```

And second `if` condition should be:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['role']) && ($_SESSION['role'] != 'admin')) { 
 // Show admin Non-admin/saf role links.
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying!
I tried to do what you said but now it says http://prntscr.com/ndm5bw
which is another role http://prntscr.com/ndm5vf

Comment: Please clarify why these changes should be made, Pupil?

Answer (score 1):

Youy need to tidy up your `if` statements. Many of them are checking two conditions when then only really need to check one.

Also you could replace your `if` statements with [`switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statements instead if the choices become numerous.

The below simplified code will show admin details to the admin flagged `$_SESSION` variable, and SAF details to the SAF flagged variable.

Also use the strict comparison tool `===` as best practise. Check for *positive matches* not negative matches (look for `===` not `!==`).

> Please note the argument list is in a different order from your original code.

```
/***
 * I would suggest using the below line to avoid error report NOTICES.
 * Setting an unset value to false also fits the later test of empty()
 ***/
if(!isset($_SESSION['role'])){
    $_SESSION['role'] = false;
}


if ($_SESSION['role'] === 'admin') { 

?>
Admin Dashboard HTML

<?php

}
elseif ($_SESSION['role'] === 'saf'){
?>

     SAF Dashboard HTML

<?php
}
elseif (!empty($_SESSION['role']) ) {
 ?>
   Some other authentication level dashboard (optional). 
<?php
}
 mysqli_close($ligaBD);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!
I did the changes that you suggested and I got this error:  Notice: Undefined index: role

Comment: @Pedro well you need to set the value of `role`. If you intend for `role` to not be set then you can just ignore those `notice` level warnings.

Comment: Updated and now it doesnt show anything :/ https://prnt.sc/ndrjfh
This is how it should be: http://prntscr.com/ndrkk9

Comment: @Pedro There was a typo I have now fixed. You should have got a notice on this. Please retry with the new code, above. Thanks.

Comment: Good morning, sorry for the late reply. I tested it and it still doesnt show anything, however I tried to change from 'role' to 'name' and isntead of 'admin' I wrote 'pedro@gmail.com' which is the username associated with the admin role. So the problem is on 'role'. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show Dashboard and saf to all the users, you can use if condition like below:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['role']) && ($_SESSION['role'] != 'admin')) {
     // Show Dashboard and saf and other links to all users.
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="admin.php">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="saf.php">SAF</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Bem-vindo, saf @login</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="https:a/"><img src="./images/mail.png" alt="la" height="13" width="20" /></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./login.html">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>

}else{
    // Show All links admin users.
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="admin.php">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="biblioteca.php">Biblioteca</a></li>
        <li><a href="conselhoadmin.php">Conselho Administrativo</a></li>
        <li><a href="saf.php">SAF</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="#">Bem-vindo, admin <?=$_SESSION['name']?></a></li>
       <li>
           <a href="https:a"><img src="./images/mail.png" alt="la" height="13" width="20" /></a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="./logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>

}
```